# How to "Animate" / Hide and then Unhide a string in java script?

Tags: javascript, animation, time, clock

Now, I'm making a very simple live clock for a webpage. I want to make the ":" between the hours and minutes and seconds to hide for a second and then unhide the next.

Here's the code:

```
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var per = h * 60 + m;
  m = checkTime(m);
  h = checkTime(h);
  s = checkTime(s);
  var am = " am";
  var pm = " pm";

  if (h > 12) {
    h = (h - 12)
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + pm.sup();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + am.sup();
  }
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}


function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it using this method

`new Date().toLocaleTimeString()`

It automatically converts time to format similar to yours.

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGrLXo**

The whole js code:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('time'), blink, str;
setInterval(function(){
    str = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    ele.innerText = (blink = !blink)?str:str=str.replace(/:/g," ");
},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the css value of your blinking `:` character's `opacity` to alernate between `0` and `1` with each second. So, if your blinker DOM element looked like this:

`<span id="blinker">:</span>`

Your code could look like this:

```
var opacity = 1;

setInterval(function(){
    var blinker = document.getElementById("blinker");
    blinker.style.opacity = opacity == 1 ? 0 : 1; //This is a ternary operator, acting as an alternator 
}, 1000);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For the clock, your **HTML** should look like:

```
<div>
<span id="hours"></span>
<span id="blinker"></span>
<span id="minutes></span>...
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var hours = document.getElementById("hours");
hours.innerHTML = ...
var minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
minutes.innerHTML = ...
```

The blinker:

```
<span id="blinker">:</span>
```

For JavaScript, you need a function that **gets** the CSS value

```
getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(val)
```

to switch between:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var blinker = document.getElementById("blinker");
    var val = window.getComputedStyle(blinker, null).getPropertyValue("display");
    switch (val) {
        case "block":
            blinker.style.display = "none";
            break;
        case "none":
            blinker.style.display = "block";
            break;
    }

}, 1000);
```

[Blinker example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lqr20cw/)

Here is the complete solution with your code. There I don't use display block. Instead I use opacity, because you change the position with *block*.

Use **setInterval** separate, outside of your startTime() function:

```
setInterval(function() { f(); }, 1000);
```

[**Complete solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ydrzogu/1/)